# Axios not showing data response after hitting the API

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, bcrypt, jsonresponse

**Calling GET request from the client app**

```
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/users/login',user)
 .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);             
 });
```

**GET request API**

```
User.findOne({email: email})
  .then(docs => {
    bcrypt.compare(password , docs.password, function(err, result) {
    if(result){
    return response.status(200).json({message : 'user found'})
   }else{
   return res.send(err);
   } });})
.catch(Err => response.send(Err))
```

[postman response message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2PDx.png)

[empty body array from client console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPOZq.png)

Answer (score 1):

You're also not sending the user back in your response.

You have `return response.status(200).json({message : 'user found'})`

You're getting the response back (judging by the picture in your post). But you also want to send the `result`.

Comment: I could see the response {message : 'user found')in postman. But not showing up in the website console

Comment: So you're searching your db for a user, and if you found a user you're sending a message of "user found" to the front end. But in your code you're not actually sending the user data back. Try something like `return response.status(200).json({result})`

Comment: I'm not getting response in data body on website console. I could get it in postman. In this case Result is true. Even this is not showing up.                                                                    config: {url: "http://localhost:5000/users/login", method: "get", data: "{"email":"Karthik@gmail.com","password":"QWEERTTY"}", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
data: {}   <----------empty array

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
```

In your API, you must indicate that the email body is from the front request.
You can also try with `post` instead of `get` because you're sending a body into your request.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send a GET request with a body which is quite uncommon. To send a GET request with body in `axios` you need to follow the below syntax.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/users/login',{
  data: user
})
 .then((res) => {
  console.log(res);             
});
```

Also make sure you are retrieving the params from the body instead of the query params which are mostly used in GET Request.

Comment: I tired. stiil not showing response message in console.config: {url: "http://localhost:5000/users/login", method: "get", data: "{"email":"Karthik@gmail.com","password":"QWEERTTY"}", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
data: {}
headers: {content-length: "2", content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"

Answer (score 0):

Please do two Changes:

1)Change console log data fetching

```
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/users/login',user)
 .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data); //**<--- Here i change -->**             
 });
```

if you find still any error then go for 2nd change

2) change your request data

```
User.findOne({email: req.body.email}) //**<--Here i change-->**
  .then(docs => {
    bcrypt.compare(password , docs.password, function(err, result) {
    if(result){
    return response.status(200).json({message : 'user found'})
   }else{
   return res.send(err);
   } });})
.catch(Err => response.send(Err))
```

generally, in API, you have to request your data through body eg. **req.body.data**

Comment: FYI , I stored req.body.email in the const email.

Comment: then go for the first option and let me know.